# web-workers in Rails projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-worker

I try to use web workers to be able to run several javascript codes at the same time. To start the worker I put the following into my javascript code section:

```
var worker = new Worker("my_task.js");
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
};
worker.postMessage("test");
```

**my_task.js** is the same folder as the file that holds the code above. This is how **my_task.js** looks like:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  self.postMessage(e.data);
}, false);
```

But there seems to be a problem with Ruby on Rails (version 3.2.1):

```
Started GET "/users/my_task.js" for 127.0.0.1 at ...
...
...
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=my_task)
```

As you can see Rails tries to send an http get request when the script is started.
How can I solve this problem? Is there a better way to use web workers in Rails projects?

Thanks

Comment: There does not seem a problem with ruby on rails, there seems to be a problem with your code because you supply `my_task` as id instead of an actual ID. Can you post your worker code please?

Comment: Where do you store my_task.js?

Comment: In the same folder as the file that holds the `worker.postMessage` code

Answer (score 6):

- Put my_task.js in `/public/javascripts`
- In your javascript code where the worker is created, use the following ERB: `var worker = new Worker("<%= javascript_path "my_task.js" %>");`
- Add `.erb` to the extension of whatever file the above javascript code is found in. So if it's `mypage.js`, it becomes `mypage.js.erb`.

The above works for me on Rails 4.2.0, ruby 2.0.0p598

Comment: Thanks! Personally I put my worker file in `lib/assets/javascripts`.

Answer (score 0):

Put my_task.js in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

the above `<% javascript_path %>`

and `lib/assets/javascripts` worked for me using Rail5