# Can't record microphone input by using recorderjs in rails environment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to record user's voice in my Rails project.

So I tried to use `[AudioRecorder][1]`, but I couldn't. I checked the example HTML works fine by using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

Then I copied 'audiodisplay.js', 'main.js', 'recorder.js' and 'recorderWorker.js' to `app/assets/javascripts/recorder/` directory.

And copy sample HTML to `app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb` without unnecessary tag:

```
<style>
...styles for the page
</style>
<div id="viz">
  <canvas id="analyser" width="1024" height="500"></canvas>
  <canvas id="wavedisplay" width="1024" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="controls">
  <img id="record" src="img/mic128.png" onclick="toggleRecording(this);">
  <a id="save" href="#"><img src="img/save.svg"></a>
</div>
```

The graph changes by surrounding sounds, so the recording seem to be working, but after stopping the sound the download button stay transparent.

In the console I can get `audioRecorder` instance, but `audioRecorder.exportWAV(doneEncoding)` returns `undefined`.

```
> audioRecorder
< Recorder {context: AudioContext, node: ScriptProcessorNode}
> audioRecorder.exportWAV(doneEncoding)
< undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you handling this on the server side?

Comment: I don't implement yet, at first I want to run the example and It failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem the `recorder.js` uses variable in it's function.

```
var WORKER_PATH = 'js/recorderjs/recorderWorker.js';
```

And it failed to read the file.

To solve the problem I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28736375/1536527).

- Put recorderWorker.js in /public/javascripts
- Rewrite path name in `recorder.js`

  var WORKER_PATH = "<%= javascript_path 'recorderWorker.js' %>";
- Rename `recorder.js` to `recorder.js.erb`